# what happens when you merge branches in keras with different shapes?

Tags: keras-2

Following is the partial code. I am trying to understand what "add" does. Why is the output of Add layer (None, 38, 300) when adding two inputs with different shapes here?

Following is the code in Keras.

```
image_model = Input(shape=(2048,))
x = Dense(units=EMBEDDING_DIM, activation="relu")(image_model)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)

language_model = Input(shape=(MAX_CAPTION_SIZE,))
y = Embedding(input_dim=VOCABULARY_SIZE, output_dim=EMBEDDING_DIM)(language_model)
y = Dropout(0.5)(y)

merged = add([x, y])
merged = LSTM(256, return_sequences=False)(merged)
merged = Dense(units=VOCABULARY_SIZE)(merged)
merged = Activation("softmax")(merged)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is the output of Add layer (None, 38, 300) when adding two inputs
>   with different shapes here?

It's a technique called broadcasting. You can find more details here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html

In the example below, the first input(16,) is broadcast along the second dimension(2,) of the second input(2,16), so that the element-wise addition can happen.

```
import keras
import numpy as np

input1 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(16,))
input2 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(2,16))
added = keras.layers.Add()([input1, input2])
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=added)
output = model.predict([np.ones((1,16)), np.ones((1,2,16))])
print(output.shape)
print(output)
```

(1, 2, 16)

[[[2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2.]
  [2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2.]]]

Comment: Thanks for the example - that really helps.